# Form Validation w/ sql + codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on creating a callback function in codeigniter to see if a certain record exists in the database, and if it does it'd like it to return a failure.

In the controller the relevent code is:

```
function firstname_check($str)
{

  if($this->home_model->find_username($str)) return false;
  true;
}
```

Then in the model I check the database using the find_username() function.

```
function find_username($str)
 {
  if($this->db->get_where('MasterDB', array('firstname' => $str)))
   {
    return TRUE;
   }

    return FALSE;
   }
```

I've used the firstname_check function in testing and it works.  I did something like

```
function firstname_check($str)
 {

   if($str == 'test') return false;
   true;
 }
```

And in that case it worked.  Not really sure why my model function isn't doing what it should.  And guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
  if($this->home_model->find_username($str)) return false;
  true;
```

Given that code snippet above, you are not returning it true. If that is your code and not a typo it should be:

```
  if($this->home_model->find_username($str)) return false;
    return true;
```

That should fix it, giving that you did not have a typo.

EDIT:
You could also just do this since the function returns true/false there is no need for the if statement:

```
function firstname_check($str)
{
  return $this->home_model->find_username($str);
}
```

Comment: I've found that it's in the query using var_dump.  There is a string which it should be finding, but it's not.  So it's always returning false.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution involved taking the query statement out of if statement, placing it into a var then counting the rows and if the rows was > 0, invalidate.

Although this is a more convoluted than I'd like.

Answer (score 0):

I find your naming kind of confusing.  Your model function is called 'find_username' but it searches for a first name.  Your table name is called 'MasterDB'.  This sounds more like a database name.  Shouldn't it be called 'users' or something similar?  I'd write it like this :

Model function :

```
function user_exists_with_firstname($firstname)
{
    $sql = 'select count(*) as user_count 
            from users 
            where firstname=?';
    $result = $this->db->query($sql, array($firstname))->result();
    return ((int) $result->user_count) > 0;
}
```

Validation callback function :

```
function firstname_check($firstname)
{
    return !$this->user_model->user_exists_with_firstname($firstname);
}
```